# D3.js v5 how to stagger every other end node (in a horizontal tree)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have some ornamentation that I will be adding later to the end nodes. Since the end nodes all are fairly close to each other (tends to happen with lots of children/ parent node), there will not be enough space. I thought an interesting solution might be to stagger the end node positions on odd number nodes.

Snippet:

```js
var margins = {top:100, bottom:300, left:100, right:100};

var height = 600;
var width = 1200;

var totalWidth = width+margins.left+margins.right;
var totalHeight = height+margins.top+margins.bottom;

var svg = d3.select('body')
.append('svg')
.attr('width', totalWidth)
.attr('height', totalHeight);

var graphGroup = svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', "translate("+margins.left+","+margins.top+")");

  var data = [

{name:"UK", tree: {
  "name": "Actors",
  "children": [

 {
   "name": "Shareholder requirements",
   "movies":d3.range(9).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_item'} }),
   "children": [
     {
       "name": "xx",
       "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
      },
      {
        "name": "xx",
        "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
       },
       {
         "name": "xx",
         "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
        },
        {
          "name": "xx",
          "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
         },
       ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Compliance track records",
    "movies":d3.range(3).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_item'} }),
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "xx",
        "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
       },
       {
         "name": "xx",
         "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
        },
        ]
   },
   {
     "name": "Shareholder funding capability",
     "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_item'} }),
     "children": [
       {
         "name": "xx",
         "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
        },
        {
          "name": "xx",
          "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
         },
         {
           "name": "xx",
           "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
          },
         ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Conflict of interest",
      "movies":d3.range(5).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_item'} }),
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "xx",
          "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
         },
         {
           "name": "xx",
           "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
          },
          {
            "name": "xx",
            "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
           },
           {
             "name": "xx",
             "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
            },
          ]
     },
     {
       "name": "Executive qualification",
       "movies":d3.range(2).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_item'} }),
       "children": [
         {
           "name": "xx",
           "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
          },
          {
            "name": "xx",
            "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
           },
           ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Executive qualification",
        "movies":d3.range(6).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_item'} }),
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "xx",
            "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
           },
           {
             "name": "xx",
             "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
            },
            ]
       },
       {
         "name": "Material supplements",
         "movies":d3.range(4).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_item'} }),
         "children": [
           {
             "name": "xx",
             "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
            },
            {
              "name": "xx",
              "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
             },
             {
               "name": "xx",
               "movies":d3.range(0).map(function(v) {return {name: v.toString()+'_movie'} })
              },
             ]
        },
  ]
}}

  ];

  //var formatComma = d3.format(",");

  var columns = 3;
  var spacing = 200;
  var vSpacing = 180;

  var regionG = graphGroup.selectAll('.region')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('g')
.attr('class', 'region')
.attr('id', (d, i) => 'region' + i)
.attr('transform', (d, k) => {
  var horSpace = (k % columns) * spacing;
  var vertSpace = ~~((k / columns)) * vSpacing;
  return "translate(" + horSpace + "," + vertSpace + ")";
});

var miniTree = d3.tree()
.size([500, 800]);




regionG.selectAll(null)
.data( function(d) {
return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants().slice(1)

})
  .enter().append("path")
.attr("transform", "translate(-25,20)") // extra positioning.
.attr("class", "link")
.attr("d", function(d) {
  return "M" + d.y + "," + d.x
+ "C" + (d.y + d.parent.y)/2 + "," + (d.x)
+ " " + (d.y +d.parent.y)/2 + "," +  (d.x)
+ " " + d.parent.y + "," + d.parent.x;
  });

/*
.attr("d", function(d) {
   return "M" + d.x + "," + d.y
 + "C" + d.x + "," + (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
 + " " + d.parent.x + "," +  (d.y + d.parent.y) / 2
 + " " + d.parent.x + "," + d.parent.y;
   });
*/

////////
var g = regionG.selectAll(null)
  .data( function(d) {return miniTree(d3.hierarchy(d.tree)).descendants() })
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", function(d) {
 return "node" + (d.children ? " node--internal" : " node--leaf");
  })
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
return "translate(" + (d.y - 25) + "," + (d.x+20) + ")";
  })

g.append("circle")
  .attr('r', function(d) {return d.depth==0 ? 25:10})
  .style('fill', function(d) {return d.depth==2 ? 'none':"#003366"})
  .style('stroke','none');

g.filter(function(d) {

return d.depth!==0;
  }).each(function(node) {

  var forceNodes = node.data.movies;
  // add a placeholder node fixed to the center:
  forceNodes.push({fx:0,fy:0,placeholder:true});
//start simulation for one node
  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation(forceNodes)
  .force("x", d3.forceX(function(d) {
  return 0;
  }).strength(0.2))
  .force("y", d3.forceY(function(d) {
  return 0;
  }).strength(0.1))
  .force("collide", d3.forceCollide().radius(function(d) {
    // change collide radius for placeholder node:
    return d.placeholder ? 12 : 4;
  }).iterations(1))
  .stop();

  simulation.tick(75);
//append circles at (0,95) -- the center coorinates of the bottom left tree node
 d3.select(this).selectAll(null)
   // don't append placeholder node:
  .data(forceNodes.filter(function(d) { return !d.placeholder }))
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("r", 3)
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x;})
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y;})
  .style('stroke',"none")
  .style('fill', function(d) {return "#4f81b9"; })



  })
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

### Question

How would I stagger the end points on every other node? (Let's say give odd ones an extra +100 x position)